# Are these two random variables independent?

Tags: probability

$X(k) = 1.02$ or $0.99$, each with probability $0.5, k = 1,2...,n$

$Y(k+1) = Y(k)X(k), Y(1) = 1.$

that is, at every step $k$ we toss a fair coin and the value obtained for  $Y$ is the value of $Y$ at $k$ times $1.02$ or $0.98$, depending on outcome.

Question: are $X(k)$ and$ Y(k$) independent random variables?

Furthermore: Can we then say that $\mathbb{E}[Y(k)X(k)] = \mathbb{E}[Y(k)]\mathbb{E}[X] = 1.005 \mathbb{E}[Y(k)]$ since $\mathbb{E}[X(k)] = 1.005$?

Although one could say that $X(k)$ is generated independently, evidently, $Y(k)$ depends on past values of $X(k)$. Therefore, the two processes are related in this sense and are not independent.

Comment: What is $Y(1)$?

Comment: Thank you, edited.

Comment: If the $X(i)$ are independent of each other then each $Y(k)$ is independent of the corresponding  $X(k)$ for the reason you give, but $\mathbf{Y}=(Y(1),Y(2),Y(3),\ldots, Y(n))$ is not independent of $\mathbf{X}=(X(1),X(2),X(3),\ldots,X(n))$ again for the reason you give.  $\mathbf{Y}$ is independent of $X(n)$

Comment: Thanks. Can we then say that E{Y(k)X(k)} = E(Y(k)}E{X} = 1.005xE{Y(k)} since E{X(k)} = 1.005 ?

Comment: Yes, though you should use MathJax/LaTeX to make your expressions readable.  You can go further and say $\mathbb E[Y(k+1)] = \mathbb E[Y(k)X(k)]= 1.005\mathbb E[Y(k)]=1.005^k$

Comment: The second value that $X(k)$ takes $0.99$, I guess...

Comment: @Henry But as you claimed before X and Y are not independent, independence is only at k, and at k,  X(k) is either 1.02 or 0.98 but never 1.005. Sorry I am still learning math formatting.

Comment: @Rick - true but $\mathbb E[Y(k)X(k)] = \mathbb E[Y(k)]\, \mathbb E[X(k)]$ by independence  and $\mathbb E[X(k)] = \frac12 0.99+\frac12 1.02 = 1.005$